# Test existing oracle table partition before adding a new one

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've already searched in the Stackoverflow existing subject but couldn't find an answer,

I try to write a pl sql script to add a partition to my existing table,
 **BUT, BEFORE THIS,** i need to verify if the partition to add is already existing in this table or not,
If exist, i have nothing to do,
If NOT, i have to create it with an alter table
here's my script that does not work :s :s

```
        CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_PARTITION AS

  V_TEST_PARTITION    INTEGER := 1;
  REQUETE             VARCHAR2(5000);

BEGIN

  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO V_TEST_PARTITION
  FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME   = 'SALES'
  AND PARTITION_NAME = 'MY_PARTITION';


  IF V_TEST_PARTITION = 0


  REQUETE := 'ALTER TABLE SALES ADD PARTITION'|| DEV || 'VALUES ('||MY_PARTITION'||') 
      TABLESPACE "STORE_DATA"';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE REQUETE;


  ELSE IF V_TEST_PARTITION = 0 THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('MY_PARTITION' is already exist');
  END IF;

END;
```

Thanks a lot you for helping

Comment: It looks like you need some spaces in your constructed query string.

Comment: What is your problem? Are you having an error? Please try to be more detailed

Comment: Error(17,3): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "REQUETE" when expecting one of the following:     * & - + / at mod remainder rem then <an exponent (**)> and or    || multiset The symbol "then" was substituted for "REQUETE" to continue.

Comment: Error(32,4): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:     if

Comment: i have this two errors !!!

Comment: You're missing a THEN; DEV is undefined; your dynamic string has some missing spaces and probably quotes; your dbms_output call has too much quotes. Try to build your procedure step by step, compiling small pieces of code instead that all the procedure in a single shot.

Comment: In addition to what the others have said, your `IF V_TEST_PARTITION = 0` has no semi-colon following it - it should be 'IF V_TEST_PARTITION = 0;`

Comment: Thanks to you all, 
problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake in your code:

```
IF V_TEST_PARTITION = 0
```

should be

```
IF V_TEST_PARTITION <> 0
```